# When do we use the word "entry"?

Tags: word-usage

> I've seen at least one blog entry that used a bytecode hack to
>   replace a CALL opcode immediately before a RETURN opcode with a jump
>   to the top of the function body.

I looked up the word "entry" on google translate. It means

> an item written or printed in a diary, list, ledger, or reference book

in such a case. But it seems not a must. If we remove it from the above sentence, it doesn't affect the sentence's meaning yet. So why do we put it there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without the word **entry** in your given example, the phrase would be referring to the blog as a whole, i.e. that the person has seen at least one blog out of many blogs which used such a bytecode hack.

Whereas, the inclusion of the word **entry** indicates that the person is referring to one particular item within a blog which may contain many items.

Answer (score 6):

You definitely don't want to remove it because the meaning will be completely different. A blog is basically a website that contains a number of articles (you can call them blog articles since they all appear in a blog). A blog entry then would be just one of those blog articles. So, saying:

> I've seen at least **one blog** that used a bytecode hack to replace a CALL opcode immediately before a RETURN opcode with a jump to the top of the function body.

would mean that you're talking about a blog as a website instead of a particular article (blog entry) from that blog.